# Run native android executable file outside zygote

Tags: android, native

Is it possible to start a native android executable file outside of zygote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that daemonizing your application using the below code in my native application makes it detach from zygote.

```
/* Daemonize */ 
daemon(0, 0); 
umask(0); 
alarm(0);
```

I'm not really sure if it really is detached from zygote but that's what pstree shows me. The only downside is that all output will not be printed anymore. In my case I don't need to print anything to the user so that is fine.